# What is the best way to get one param from form (Play2 Framework)?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am want to create simple form for searching records via one parameter (for example, name).
Seems like creating a class with one property (name) and than use helpers for forms - is not a best way.
Is there any examles how can I get POST data from request and fetch property value from that data?

Thanks a lot for wasting your time.

Comment: `String key = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("name")[0];` is my best solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered your own question, I just want to provide some more information:

You are right about creating a class with one single property, however keep in mind that you can use validation annotations (like `@Required`, `@Email`, etc.) in this class - so if there is some (super) complex logic behind this property this might also be a valuable option.

The second solution would be to use `DynamicForm`s - you use them when you don't really have a model that is backing up the submission form. It goes like this:

```
public static Result index() {
    DynamicForm requestData = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    String name = requestData.get("name");
    return ok(name);
}
```

And of course the third option to get the values is like you mentioned:

```
String name = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("name")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the example of `DynamicForm`. I'll try it. Validation tags will work always, or only if my class extends some class like `Entity`?

Comment: @gooamoko Validation annotations should work even in the simplest case: 

`public class User {

    @Required
    public String name;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not what to use form validation, I don't think you need to create a class. Instead, you can use AJAX function like [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), that will be route to your specific `controller` function. Moreover, you can call your `model` function from your `controller` then at last return the result. The result will be caught by the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function.

```
$.ajax
  type: "POST"
  url: url
  data: data
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
```

Comment: I need to get POST parameter on the server side. And I know about AJAX, but I am sending data to the server via simple <FORM> tag.